# Summing over C contiguous array in numpy returns wrong answer

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array:

```py
values = np.array(
    [[0.00000000000000000000000e+00,
      0.00000000000000000000000e+00],
     [-4.79999759999999625000000e+14,
      -0.00000000000000000000000e+00],
     [4.79999759999999625000000e+14,
      -0.00000000000000000000000e+00],
     [-0.00000000000000000000000e+00,
      -4.79999759999999625000000e+14],
     [-3.74998499999999072265625e+12,
      -3.74998499999999072265625e+12],
     [3.74998499999999072265625e+12,
      -3.74998499999999072265625e+12],
     [-0.00000000000000000000000e+00,
      4.79999759999999625000000e+14],
     [-3.74998499999999072265625e+12,
      3.74998499999999072265625e+12],
     [3.74998499999999072265625e+12,
      3.74998499999999072265625e+12]]
)
```

It contains 0, 4.79999759999999625e+14, 3.74998499999999072265625e+12 and their negative counterparts.

```py
print(np.sum(values, axis=0))
```

Should result in [0.  0.] (or at least something very very small), but it does not. Its result is `[ 0.         -0.01855469]`.

I figured, this is a floating point precision error and the cause is that numpy is unable to do pair wise summation, so I tried as well:

```py
values_T = np.array(
    [[0.000000000000000000000000e+00,
      -4.799997599999996250000000e+14,
      4.799997599999996250000000e+14,
      -0.000000000000000000000000e+00,
      -3.749984999999990722656250e+12,
      3.749984999999990722656250e+12,
      -0.000000000000000000000000e+00,
      -3.749984999999990722656250e+12,
      3.749984999999990722656250e+12],
     [0.000000000000000000000000e+00,
      -0.000000000000000000000000e+00,
      -0.000000000000000000000000e+00,
      -4.799997599999996250000000e+14,
      -3.749984999999990722656250e+12,
      -3.749984999999990722656250e+12,
      4.799997599999996250000000e+14,
      3.749984999999990722656250e+12,
      3.749984999999990722656250e+12]]
)

print(np.sum(values_T, axis=1))
```

Which results in `[ 0.         -0.00927734]`. Somehow, the error is halved but it's still not correct.

Both arrays are C contiguous (checked via `np.ndarray.flags`).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I thought that numpy was struggling with the sum because it was forced to calculate the sum in order in the first instance, which would mean that the order of magnitudes difference results in a floating point precision error. But if I would then make sure that the values that are summed can be accessed in one go (they're C contiguous), numpy could do pair wise summation/cascade summation to find the correct answer of 0.

Comment: `numpy.sum` does not try to minimize this kind of error.  In the `math` module, there is a `fsum` that does, `math.fsum(values[:,1])`

Comment: @hpaulj, yes, thank you! that fixes it. if you post it as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: `np.sum` has a paragraph on floating point errors.  I think that explains the case where it halves the error.  It mentions the use of `fsum`.

Comment: If the size of the error surprises you, consider `math.ulp()` which tells you the value of the least significant bit of a floating point value.  `math.ulp(-4.79999759999999625000000e+14) == 0.0625`.  64-bit floats have about 16 digits of decimal accuracy, so it makes sense the error is 2 digits after the decimal for a +14 exponent.

Comment: I'd find that better to read with the three (absolute) values replaced by `a`, `b` and `0` (and define those two variables).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps sort the values by absolute value before summing them?

```
v = values[:, 1]
print(v)
print(v.sum())
print(v[abs(v).argsort()].sum())
```

Output:

```
[ 0.0000000e+00 -0.0000000e+00 -0.0000000e+00 -4.7999976e+14
 -3.7499850e+12 -3.7499850e+12  4.7999976e+14  3.7499850e+12
  3.7499850e+12]
-0.00927734375
0.0
```

A bigger test, with arrays of 10-20 random numbers and their negations, shuffled:

```
for n in range(10, 21):
  a = np.random.random(n)
  a *= 2 ** np.random.randint(50, size=n)
  a = np.hstack((a, -a))
  np.random.shuffle(a)
  print(a[abs(a).argsort()].sum(), a.sum())
```

Sample output showing that the sorted sum was always 0.0 while the unsorted sum rarely was:

```
0.0 3.335706423968077e-05
0.0 0.00945821466302732
0.0 0.0009765625
0.0 -0.012045614654198289
0.0 0.000331806018948555
0.0 0.010692596435546875
0.0 0.0
0.0 0.009552001953125
0.0 -0.005477488040924072
0.0 -0.006590104184041934
0.0 0.001953125
```